# A button in a UI, that will export the console log in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, console

(i will sound a as a beggar, but i really need it. )
(i am not a c Sharp programmer, i just need this for a project)

So.. i need a button that will export your logs from that 'play session' into the game folder with the date and time saying when it was exported. but then i need to link that script to a button on a world space canvas. (i am a level designer but i need to do this since the programmer is away for nearly a week.)

I will be really thankful. sorry if i sound like a choosing beggar.

Thanks!

Comment: This is something we usually don't do here. Your question is off-topic due to asking for a tool/library. However I created a script a while ago for exactly the same thing: [`LogExportButton.cs`](https://gist.github.com/der-hugo/d511de7ba3164185f2f97b08428d31d3) simply attach this component to the according `Button` it automatically stores all log messages and writes them to a file when clicking. Note that of course it only works for log messages received **after** `Awake`. If you need these as well adjust the [Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html)

Comment: @derHugo Hey! Thank you!. What do i adjust the execution order, do i put LogExportButton.cs at the very top? also what do you mean, ' only works for log messages received after Awake'

Comment: also @derHugo 
'    ///TODO: Just for testing generating some debug logs
    /// <para>TODO: Remove this!</para>' on line 80 / 81.    if i should remove this and from what line do it remove anything?

Comment: @Chromy XMl document comments always refer to a complete member of a class .. in this case the entire `Update` method. And it means that since the callback is added in the `Awake` method any log happening before is not tracked yet. Yes you would move it to the top in the execution order before the `Default time`